# What should I do with Arduino starter kit?

Tags: arduino

This is not actually a problem but I need your advice. I live in Greece and I want to start learning how to make things with Arduino. I can order the starter kit which costs 80 euros which is a good price, but with the shipping it's 100 euros (136 dollars). Should I save money to pay so much for this? I'm afraid that the starter kit does not provide enough for what I want to do and I will have to order more stuff. Just to have an idea how expensive they are (and not to mention the availability) 10 euros for few resistors are too much. What should I buy?

Comment: "does not provide enough for what I want to do" - what do you want to do?

Comment: TI's MSP430 was $4.30, there's some monster bargains to be had with STM32 Discovery boards too if you're not set on Arduino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There many brands of Arduino starter kit, but most of them contains the basic parts such as: couple of leds, some resistors, diodes, and perhaps a servo engine or a 8-bit shifter.

The purpose of those kits is to put you on the right path as a beginner; They usually include a hard copy/PDF book with some circuits you can create with the parts they contain.

The real question is - do you want to make something specific? Or, do you just want to have a starting point. Usually the resistors and other parts supplied with those kits fits the circuits described in the attached book, so if that's your intention, you should be good to go.